# Request was rejected because the Authorization header did not contain a valid bearer token (JWT)

Tags: reactjs, api, chat, http-status-code-400

I tried cloning [this](https://github.com/pusher/react-pusher-chatkit-app) project to play with the chat application but I am running across a few issues:

1) I receive a 400 error which states "The request was rejected because the Authorization header did not contain a valid bearer token (JWT)."

2) Another error that says the user does not exist

3) If I try and send a message I see an error with the sendMessage function has a typeerror

I did change all the info so it is specific to me (also the room id)

Here are the errors:
[image: Imgur]

Here are lines 46-52 in ChatApp.js:

```
.then(currentRoom => {
        this.setState({
          currentRoom,
          users: currentRoom.userIds
        });
      })
      .catch(error => console.log(error));
  }

  addMessage(text) {
    console.log(this.state);
    this.state.currentUser
      .sendMessage({
        text,
        roomId: this.state.currentRoom.id
      })
      .catch(error => console.error("error", error));
  }
```